# Correct place to close DataOutputStream?

Tags: dataoutputstream

I'm currently working on a program that creates a thread for each file read in, reads through it and writes specific info to another file.. My issue here is I am not sure where exactly I need to close the DataOutputStream...

Closing it within the loop just stalls the program and results in no output.
Heres a bit of code: This is the synchronized block where I believe the writing needs to take place.

```
   //Takes in zip,city,state and writes them to ZipCityState file
   class Counter {
      public synchronized void update(int zip, String city, String state){
        try {
          DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("ZipCityState.dat"));
          dos.writeInt(zip);
          dos.writeUTF(city);
          dos.writeUTF(state);
          count++;
          }
         catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
         }      
      }   
   }
```

Below is the run method for the threads

```
 public void run(){
     DataInputStream dis = null;
     int zip = 0;
     String city = null;
     String state = null;
     double longitude = 0;
     double latitude = 0;
     int timeZone = 0;
     int DST = 0;
     int recCount = 0;

 try {
 dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(theFile));
 while(true){
    zip = dis.readInt();
    city = dis.readUTF();
    state = dis.readUTF();
    longitude = dis.readDouble();
    latitude = dis.readDouble();
    timeZone = dis.readInt();
    DST = dis.readInt();
    ata.addCity(city);
    recCount++;
    c.update(zip, city, state);
 }
 }
 catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
 }

 catch(EOFException eof) {
    System.out.printf("Filenameis: %s completed, record count is %,d %n", theFile, recCount);
        try{
            dis.close();
       }
           catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error closing file "+theFile);
           }    
 }
 catch(IOException ie){
    ie.printStackTrace();
 } 

 }// end run
```

Comment: try using the append parameter in the fileoutputstream, and then close your dataoutputstream in the same class where you create it.  or create your dataoutputstream outside of this class and keep it open until done with it completely

Comment: Yeah, much better idea.. I decided to close the DataOutputStream AFTER all threads are finished and that seems to have done the trick.